# Schema.DescribeSObjectResult has no member named layouttable

Tags: apex

I have been using this piece of code :

```
List<Schema.SObjectType> gd = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().Values();   

List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();

for(Schema.SObjectType f : gd)
{
    Schema.DescribeSObjectResult d = f.getDescribe();
    if(  d.layoutable == true ) {
        options.add(new SelectOption(f.getDescribe().getName(),f.getDescribe().getLabel()));
    }
}
```

Which is giving me the error

> Expression of type Schema.DescribeSObjectResult has no member named
>   layoutable

Other properties seem to work just fine. I have been referencing this documentation : http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_describesobjects_describesobjectresult.htm

Any one has suggestions or any clue what is happening here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation you have refered to is the documentation for the SOAP API.

What you want is the [documentation for Apex Describe Information](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dynamic_describe_objects_understanding.htm) which is slightly different and doesn't give you as much information.

Comment: Thanks for help @Alex Tennant , I have also been through this link [here](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_sobject_describe.htm#apex_methods_system_sobject_describe) but it doesn't seem to expose the property **layoutable**, any way I could achieve this with apex?

Comment: @ShaikhMohdNadeem You could call the SOAP API from Apex. To do this you'd either need to write your own web service calls that construct the required XML, or you could export the WSDL and then import it back in, although it may need some tweaking after import as WSDL2Apex doesn't support all WSDL features. I don't know of an existing Apex wrapper for the SOAP API unfortunately (although that doesn't mean that one doesn't exist).

Comment: Thanks @Alex Tennant!!! This seems to be the only solution as of now, requiring a lot of work to achieve a small functionality which as I write this comment is not mission critical. Thanks for your time and guidance I appreciate.